# How do I create an accent button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a raised 'accent' button in Flutter - that is, with the background the same color as the app's accent theme.  Here's my code:

```
new RaisedButton(
  onPressed: _signInPressed,
  child: new Text('Sign in with Google'),
  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
)
```

Problem is the text color is still black.  How do I set the text color to be white like in the AppBar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's currently no official way to get accent button.
You can make you own though:

```
class AccentButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final Widget child;

  const AccentButton({this.child, this.onPressed, Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);

    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: onPressed,
      child: child,
      textColor: theme.accentTextTheme.button.color,
      highlightColor: theme.accentColor,
      color: theme.accentColor,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: For me that creates a button with a gray background and blue text (in an app with the default material theme).  What I'm looking for is a button with a blue background and white text

Comment: That's the way you should make your buttons use the accent theme (or using directly textTheme` property). But it seems that their implementation is wrong. In their code, in no situation will we have an accent background

Comment: Here made it for you

Comment: Thanks! That does the job (although personally I used "highlightColor: theme.highlightColor" so that the highlight can be seen to 'spread' like in the Floating Action Button)